# Automatically create and remove desktop shortcut to USB device?

Tags: windows, usb, shortcuts, removable-media

Is any possible to have:

- When I plug in a USB drive, a shortcut to it is created on the desktop automatically?
- When I unplug in a USB drive, the shortcut to it is removed from the desktop automatically?

Comment: Please don't delete your questions and then repost them to gain interest (or whatever you're attempting by doing it). If you'd like to draw more  attention to an existing question, wait until it's a couple days old and then [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Automatically create and remove desktop shortcut to USB device?

You can use TweakNow DriveShortcut:

> When a CD, a DVD, or an external hard disk added or removed from the computer, Windows will broadcast a message to all running programs to notify them about this new change. TweakNow DriveShortcut sits quietly on the tray area waiting for this kind of message. When the message received, depending on the message content, **TweakNow DriveShortcut will automatically create or delete drive icon from the desktop**.
>
> License: Freeware

...

> On the configuration window you can set for which type of drive an icon should be created and you can also have the program to remember the position of the drives icon on the dektop.
>
> [image]

Source [Create Shortcut for CD/DVD or USB Disk on the Desktop](http://www.tweaknow.com/DriveShortcut.php):

---

#### Alternatives

The following search https://www.google.com/search?q=desktop+shortcut+usb gives a number of alternative solutions ...

Comment: @ DavidPostill thanks for response,but without using software is it possible?any config?batch?

Comment: Not as far as I know :/